# Importing existing Azure resources with Terraform written using modules and data resource blocks

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-modules, terraform-import

Trying to import existing resources to current code which includes  KeyVault, keyvault-policies, diagnostic settings, cosmos db, storage accounts with containers blobs que and function apps. All code written using modules and all resources are integrated or configured with each other.

Tried multiple ways but none of the resources are getting imported and imports failing. For example, When I import storage account, it shows some errors with tenant/subscription mismatch with KeyVault or diagnostic settings. Same happens with cosmos db and all.

All resources in same tenant/subscription/resource-group. Also the code contains data  resource blocks which shows multiple errors.

The existing resources are created  with some other TF code which is unavailable but the state files are there.

After trying enough I feel whether it’s even possible to import them.

Requesting suggestions on bestways to import these. Any suggestion or solution will be highly appreciated

I tried importing commands with modules names but it's failing with error:

```
terraform import module.entitlement_storage_account.azurerm_resource_group.rg /subscriptions/<<MY-Subscription-ID>>/resourceGroups/<<MY-ReSourceGroup>>

│ Error: resources.GroupsClient#Get: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=401 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=401 Code="InvalidAuthenticationTokenTenant" Message="The access token is from the wrong issuer 'https://sts.windows.net/<<MY-TENANT-ID>>/'. It must match the tenant 'https://sts.windows.net/Directory ID
/' associated with this subscription. Please use the authority (URL) 'https://login.windows.net/<<MY-Directory-ID>>' to get the token. Note, if the subscription is transferred to another tenant there is no impact to the services, but information about new tenant could take time to propagate (up to an hour). If you just transferred your subscription and see this error message, please try back later."
│
│   with module.deployment_storage_account.data.azurerm_resource_group.rgrp[0],
│   on ..\..\modules\storage-account\main.tf line 14, in data "azurerm_resource_group" "rgrp":
│   14: data "azurerm_resource_group" "rgrp" {
╷
│ Error: resources.GroupsClient#Get: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=401 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=401 Code="InvalidAuthenticationTokenTenant" Message="The access token is from the wrong issuer 'https://sts.windows.net/<<MY-TENANT-ID>>/'. It must match the tenant 'https://sts.windows.net/<<MY-Directory-ID>>/' associated with this subscription. Please use the authority (URL) 'https://login.windows.net/<<MY-Directory-ID>>' to get the token. Note, if the subscription is transferred to another tenant there is no impact to the services, but information about new tenant could take time to propagate (up to an hour). If you just transferred your subscription and see this error message, please try back later."
│
│   with module.ingestion_storage.data.azurerm_resource_group.rgrp[0],
│   on ..\..\modules\storage-account\main.tf line 14, in data "azurerm_resource_group" "rgrp":
│   14: data "azurerm_resource_group" "rgrp" {
```

Comment: Can you share the module code you have? @Mukteswar Patnaik

Comment: Can you provide more specifics about the exact issue you're encountering while trying to import resources with Terraform? Any specific error messages would be really helpful.

Comment: Added Error details @Jahnavi/@soysoliscarlos

Comment: The error is related to the authentication issue. Have you logged into the current tenant using `az login` in CLI? @MukteswarPatnaik

Answer (score 0):

[`terraform import`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/import) is used to import the existing resources into current terraform state file as you already mentioned.

***Need to verify below:***

In your case, it is related to the authentication token. You need to check the if the token is from the correct issuer and matches the tenant associated with the subscription.

While running terraform code configuration in Azure CLI make sure that you have logged in to the correct tenant directory. Use below command before running the terraform code.

```bash
az login --tenant TENANT_ID
```

[image]

Once you have logged in, Set the subscription with the below CLI command.

```bash
 az account set -s SUBSCRIPTION_ID
```

> The access token is from the wrong issuer 'https://sts.windows.net/<>/'. It must match the tenant 'https://sts.windows.net/<>/' associated with this subscription: -

And the above error clearly states that the access token is from the wrong issuer. So, it is not related to the `terraform import` command.

Check this `https://login.windows.net/<Directory-ID>` authority URL for token retrieval. Pass `<<MY-Directory-ID>>` with the Tenant directory ID associated with your subscription.

*After checking the above, I tried importing a resource which is already existed in my environment and was able to import it successfully.*

`terraform import azurerm_resource_group.example <ResourceID>`

[image]